# "default value" of allocated struct pointer in C

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am storing the input data which includes the specific order, so I choose to use array to sort them:

```c
struct Node** array = (struct Node**)malloc(sizeof(Node**) * DEFAULT_SIZE);

int i;
int size = DEFAULT_SIZE;
while(/* reading input */) {
    // do something
    int index = token;    // token is part of an input line, which specifies the order
    struct Node* node = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    *node = (struct Node){value, index};
    // do something

    if (index >= size) {
        array = realloc(array, index + 1);
        size = index + 1;
    }

    array[index] = node;
}
```

I am trying to loop through the array and do something when the node exists at the index

```c
int i;
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (/* node at array[i] exists */) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

How can I check if node exists at the specific index of the array? (Or what is the "default value" of the struct node after I allocated its memory?) I only know it is not `NULL`...

Should I use `calloc` and try `if ((int)array[index] != 0)`? Or there is a better data structure I am able to use?

Comment: there is no default value, just garbage if you don't initialize it.

Comment: `struct Node* node = (struct Node){value, index};` are you sure?

Comment: 1 question in a post please. Note that primarily opinion based questions are off-topic according to [help/on-topic].

Comment: Add a counter `int count = 0;` that counts the number of allocated structures. When  accessing structure in the array at index `i`, check if `i < count` if yes, ok it's allocated, if no, allocate that structure, check for null, put the pointer into the array (at `[i]`) and increment `count` (assuming `i < DEFAULT_SIZE`, and that every `j < i` positions in array are all already allocated).

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre edited... sorry but I am not familiar with struct and pointers.

Comment: There is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714). Don't `realloc` to the pointer itself, (e.g. `array = realloc(array, index + 1);` - if `realloc` fails (and it will), you create a memory leak. Instead `void *tmp = realloc(array, index + 1); if (tmp != NULL) array = tmp;` Also, don't `realloc` by `1` (horribly inefficient), instead allocate some reasonable number of pointers and increase by `times 3/2` or `times 2` with each reallocation.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7240365/pointer-default-value and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21067199/do-i-need-to-initiallizeset-to-0-memory-after-calling-realloc and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32732449/is-it-common-practice-to-memset-reallocated-memory-to-0 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347766/how-many-elements-are-full-in-a-c-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `realloc` (or `malloc`) your list of pointers, the system resizes/moves the array, copying your data if needed, and reserving more space ahead *without changing the data*, so you get what was there before. You cannot rely on the values.

Only `calloc` does a zero init, but you cannot `calloc` when you `realloc`.

For starters you should probably use `calloc`:

```
struct Node** array = calloc(DEFAULT_SIZE,sizeof(*array));
```

In your loop, just use `realloc` and set the new memory to `NULL` so you can test for null pointers

Note that your `realloc` size is incorrect, you have to multiply by the size of the element. Also update the `size` after reallocation or that won't work more than once.

Note the tricky `memset` which zeroes only the unallocated data without changing the valid pointer data. `array+size` computes the proper address size due to pointer arithmetic, but the size parameter is in bytes, so you have to multiply by `sizeof(*array)` (the size of the element)

```
if (index >= size)
   {
      array = realloc(array, (index + 1)*sizeof(*array));  // fixed size
      memset(array+size,0,(index+1-size) * sizeof(*array));  // zero the rest of elements
      size = index+1;  // update size
   }
```

aside:

- `realloc` for each element is inefficient, you should realloc by chunks to avoid too many system calls/copies
- I have simplified the `malloc` calls, no need to cast the return value of `malloc`, and also better to pass `sizeof(*array)` instead of `sizeof(Node **)`. In case the type of `array` changes you're covered (also protects you from one-off errors with starred types)

Answer (score 1):

The newly-allocated memory contains garbage and reading a pointer from uninitialized memory is a bug.

If you allocated using `calloc( DEFAULT_SIZE, sizeof(Node*) )` instead, the contents of the array would be defined: all bits would be set to zero.  On many implementations, this is a `NULL` pointer, although the standard does not guarantee it.  Technically, there could be a standard-conforming compiler that makes the program crash if you attempt to read a pointer with all bits set to zero.

(Only language lawyers need to worry about that, though. In practice, even the fifty-year-old mainframes people bring up as the example of a machine where `NULL` was not binary 0 updated its C compiler to recognize 0 as a `NULL` pointer, because that broke too much code.)

The safe, portable way to do what you want is to initialize every pointer in the array to `NULL`:

```
struct Node** const array = malloc(sizeof(Node**) * DEFAULT_SIZE);
// Check for out-of-memory error if you really want to.
for ( ptrdiff_t i = 0; i < DEFAULT_SIZE; ++i )
  array[i] = NULL;
```

After the loop executes, every pointer in the array is equal to `NULL`, and the `!` operator returns 1 for it, until it is set to something else.

The `realloc()` call is erroneous.  If you do want to do it that way, the size argument should be the new number of elements times the element size.  That code will happily make it a quarter or an eighth the desired size.  Even without that memory-corruption bug, you’ll find yourself doing reallocations far too often, which might require copying the entire array to a new location in memory.

The classic solution to that is to create a linked list of array pages, but if you’re going to `realloc()`, it would be better to multiply the array size by a constant each time.

Similarly, when you create each `Node`, you’d want to initialize its pointer fields, if you care about portability.  No compiler this century will generate less-efficient code if you do.

If you only allocate nodes in sequential order, an alternative is to create an array of `Node` rather than `Node*`, and maintain a counter of how many nodes are in use. A modern desktop OS will only map in as many pages of physical memory for the array as your process writes to, so simply allocating and not initializing a large dynamic array does not waste real resources in *most* environments.

One other mistake that’s probably benign: the elements of your array have type `struct Node*`, but you allocate `sizeof(Node**)` rather than `sizeof(Node*)` bytes for each.  However, the compiler does not type-check this, and I am unaware of any compiler where the sizes of these two kinds of object pointer could be different.

Answer (score 0):

You might need something like this

```
unsigned long i;
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (array[i]->someValidationMember==yourIntValue) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Edit.
The memory to be allocated must be blank. Or if an item is deleted just simply change the Node member to zero or any of your choice.

Comment: you mean that you'll test unitialized memory for an integer value? that's risky. What it a valid cell is deallocated, then reallocated. It will have the validation value at the proper offset, but won't be valid.

Comment: The memory to be allocated should always be cleared thats all. or when deleting a node, just allocate its member to zero.

Comment: `i+=sizeof(struct Node)` is wrong. It should be `i++`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre sorry, thank you for pointing out. hahaha i edited my correct answer to wrong.

Comment: `(*(array+i))->...` should be written as `array[i]->...`

Comment: it's the same though. you can try to compile it